# Use interfaces in JAX-WS web methods

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws

I need to use an interface as a parameter and as a return type in a JAX-WS web method. When starting my server I receive an `IllegalAnnotationsException`, which tells me that JAXB cannot handle interfaces.

I tried to annotate my class, method result and method parameters with `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlElement(type = ...)` respectively, but this does not work.

**How can I use an interface as an parameter and as a result type in a JAX-WS web method?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [@XmlJavaTypeAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html). Maybe it will do the trick. More information available in [here](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html#Use__XmlJavaTypeAdapter).

Comment: Thanks, that worked so far, but it seems a bit complicated for me. Is this the only possible solution? Can you explain why `@XmlElement(type=...)` does not work?

Comment: @ManuelFaux - Which JAX-WS implementation are you using?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I use JBoss JAX-WS 2.2

Comment: Thanks I solved it with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`. But I'm still curious why `@XmlElement` does not work.